# Popup Dialogue in WebView out of current display but perfectly working in chrome browser

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, android-webview

When open in Google Chrome

[image]

When using Android WebView

[image]

When i use Google Chrome it's popup on current display view

But when i use WebView it's going center webpage then scroll down for showing dialogue.

What i should do now?

```
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();       
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setInitialScale(100);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.measure(100, 100);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<HTML><BODY><H3>Test</H3></BODY></HTML>","text/html","utf-8","");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.loadUrl(home_url);
```

WebChromeclient

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if(progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

            }
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

            if(progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
```

I try to use this correction of this popup but it's not working

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {


            WebView newWebView = new WebView(Main2Activity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution of this by using NestedWebView & Now everything working perfectly.